# How to draw such graphics in Excel or R?

Tags: excel, r, graphics

I hope you can help me. In this graphics

[image: Graphics]

you can see the density D versus Phi and Sigma for a numeric data set. How can I plot such graphics in Excel or R? I have googled around but nothing found yet.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older questions which still don't have answers.

Comment: image with a small number of colours is simple enough: image(volcano, col = grey(seq(0, 1, length = 5)))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [filled.contour](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/graphics/html/filled.contour.html). I edited the example given in the documentation slightly (added `nlevels = 5`) and got the following:

[image]

It looks somewhat like what you want, but it's going to be hard to recreate your examples without data. For reference, here is the code I used:

```
require(grDevices) # for colours
filled.contour(volcano, color = terrain.colors, asp = 1, nlevels=5)
```

Comment: @TuncJamgocyan -- Glad Edward was able to help you. You can indicate that this answered your question by 'accepting', by clicking on the check-mark just to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a reference to get you started: http://freecode.com/articles/creating-charts-and-graphs-with-gnu-r